# Solutions to group elements in different pairs

Tags: data-structures, neo4j, tree, grouping, graph-databases

I am working on grouping of elements for large dataset in least amount of time.

Below is small dataset example of the same:

```
Input:
pairs = [[1,2],[8,10],[4,8],[3,4],[2,3],[5,6],[6,7],[9,4],[11,12],[13,10],[16,1],[78,79],[61,3],[93,94]]
```

How to derive output:
If any of the element is present in another pair then both pair can be grouped. This way traverse all pairs and create different groups.

```
Output: -
[{1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 13, 16, 61}, {5, 6, 7}, {11, 12}, {78, 79}, {93, 94}]
```

Question:

- What is the best way to solve this problem?
  e.g.: graph database(neo4j) or any specific readily available algorithm.
- any other alternatives which is not listed in example solution(neo4j, algorithm) above?

Below output is expected and solution should consume less time with large dataset.

```
Expected Output: -
[{1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 13, 16, 61}, {5, 6, 7}, {11, 12}, {78, 79}, {93, 94}]
```

Comment: What sort of scale is your actual data likely to be? There are many ways to solve this ranging from "just write a script in Python" to an "MPP cluster using Spark". Knowing the scale will help inform a sensible answer.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Thanks for reviewing and helping with question. It is for 4M pairs. Is there any existing algorithm that can be used for same?

Comment: You definitely want to read about [disjoint-set (aka union-find)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).